# error: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and I am working in the client-side with a regular js and I got this error:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

my server code is:

```
app.get('/connect', function (req, res) {
    console.log("connect to the user");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'connect.html'));
});

app.post('/connect', function (req, res) {
    const userNameEnter = req.body.userName;
    const passwordEnter = req.body.password;

// //entering if the user and pass are correct
if (userNameEnter !== undefined && passwordEnter !== undefined) {
    User.findOne({ userName: userNameEnter }, function (err, user) {
        console.log(err);
        if (user !== null) { //can enter
            if (user.userPassword === passwordEnter) {
                res.json({
                    status: "seccess",
                    user: "canEnter"
                });
                console.log("can enter");
                res.redirect("/gameManage/" + user.id);
            } else {//cant enter
                res.json({
                    status: "seccess",
                    user: "notOk"
                });
            }
        } else {//cant enter
            res.json({
                status: "seccess",
                user: "notOk"
            });
            console.log("cant enter");
        }
    });
}
console.log(newUser);
```

});

I have to send the JSON because the js needs to know what to do next.
How can I redirect it in another way so I do have the parameter of the userId in the URL line?

Comment: You are doing `res.redirect` after `res.json`, hence the error

Comment: @warl0ck I know that but I have to do them both, so I can I fix it?

Comment: You *can't*. You can't send a JSON response *and* a redirect response. It's one or the other.

Comment: @deceze but if I need to do them both... is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You probably just want to send a URL inside the JSON response and the client will go to that URL via Javascript. You don't want to redirect the HTTP response.

Comment: @deceze so I should send the url via the JSON and redirect it in the javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send response to the client and then also redirect the client. You should send the redirect path to the client and then redirect from client side using javascript

```
res.json({
     status: "seccess",
     user: "canEnter",
     redirectPath: "/gameManage/" + user.id
});
```

On client side

```
if (response.redirectPath) {
    window.location.href = response.redirectPath;
}
```